# Moving files (within the same disk) means "copy and delete"?

Tags: 9.0-pie, file-management

I have Moto E6 phone with Android 9 Pie and external SD card, I need to move large folder to another location on the same card but all file explorers I tried so far were trying to **copy** data to the new location and only then delete it from old location

Is this the way android is moving files/folders? The process takes forever and (if SD card doesn't have enough space for **TWO** copies of the same data, the process is terminated with error)

Once the phone was connected to windows PC, I was able to map internal storage as a drive and just move the folder from one location to another in a second.

Is there any way to force Android to actually move data to the new location without copying?

Comment: not sure about the MTP protocol or how API work, but `mv` works fine to me on cmd line

Comment: @alecxs But mv works on an external (real) sd-card only on via adb or on a rooted device via su. Apps have to use the Java API an I am not sure if the Java API contains a move command.

Comment: @alecxs Sorry my comment was a bit unclear. I was only talking about file modifications especially for file deletion I know that this is not possible on an external sd-card since Android 9 without root permissions. Reading is still possible. File creation I don't know, and I am also not sure if file moving is something special or a combination of file creation plus deletion from a permission perspective.

Comment: looks like there is no official recommended 
way handling files https://stackoverflow.com/q/4178168